# Calculate the volume of the solid: $S=\{(x,y,z) \in R^3: x^2+y^2 \le 4; 0 \le z \le x^2+y^2+4\}$

Tags: integration, volume

How can I calculate the volume of the solid from the following equation using double integral?

$$S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3: x^2+y^2 \le 4; 0 \le z \le x^2+y^2+4\}$$

I have been able to graph the solid and I do understand the concept working in $\mathbb R^2$ but I am not sure how in $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb R^3$ you write the volume of the solid in terms of $dx dy dz$, integrating $x$ between $-2$ and $2$, $y$ between $-\sqrt{4-x^2}$ and   $\sqrt{4-x^2}$, and $z$ between $0$ and $x^2+y^2+4$. The interpretation is that you count infinitesimally small cubes. In $\mathbb R^2$, you just integrate over the disk in the $xy$ plane, but now the volume element is a rectangular parallelepiped, with volume $dx dy (x^2+y^2+4)$. This is equivalent to doing the integration in the $z$ direction before.

Comment: How did you obtain that interval for $y$? Why not $0 \le y \le 2$?

Comment: I've just looked at the first equation. Notice that $x^2+y^2\le 4$ is the equation of a disk with radius $2$. For any given $x$ in that interval, you get a range of $y$ values that depends on $x$. you get $0\le y\le 2$ only for $x=2$. But in fact $y$ can also be negative. That would satisfy the inequality as well. If you would go to $x=1$, for $y=2$ you get $x^2+y^2=5\gt 4$, which is not valid. Therefore you rewrite the firs inequality as $y^2\le 4-x^2$. When you take the square root, you need to consider the possibility that $y$ can also be negative.

Comment: But if I was only working with the positive values, then it would be from $0 \le y \le 2$?

Comment: You cannot have $x=y=2$. You can integrate $y$ from -2 to 2, but then $x$ will have the same $\pm\sqrt{4-y^2}$ range

Answer (score 1):

There's a general formula for finding certain volumes using double integrals. Suppose $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a closed bounded region in the $xy$-plane, and $z=z_1(x,y)$ and $z=z_2(x,y)$ are two functions such that $z_1(x,y)\le z_2(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in D$. Then the volume of the solid enclosed between the graphs of $z=z_1(x,y)$ and $z=z_2(x,y)$ over the region $D$ is given by
$$\text{Volume}=\iint\limits_D \left(z_2(x,y)-z_1(x,y)\right)\,dxdy.$$

In this example the solid cylinder $x^2+y^2\le4$ gives us the vertical walls of the solid and tells us that the domain $D$ in the $xy$-plane is the disk $x^2+y^2\le4$. The "floor" is the function $z_1(x,y)=0$ and the "ceiling" is the function $z_2(x,y)=x^2+y^2+4$. Setting up and evaluating this double integral will give you the desired volume.

Also, you will want to switch to polar coordinates to evaluate this particular double integral most efficiently.